# The same boolean cuts right, cut half way and doesn't cut, at the same time

Tags: modifiers

I am doing an hospital with windows. 2 Objects with multiple meshes inside. The windows are the boolean.
I created first the hospital, it has 5 different buildings that all touching one another. Then made the windows, each one from the ones already existing (shift+D) within the object in Edit Mode. And made the boolean. All good. But then I changed a bit the topology of the hospital object, and random meshes of the window object started working wrong.
I solved the problem once, by going into the window object and replacing the not-working windows with working windows. No big deal.
I changed again the hospital object and... boom, again random windows stopped working. Looked for double vertices, weird faces, face orientation... I don't know why they shift.
Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong ? Thanks
I am adding an image.[image: booleans going wrong,visual explanation]

Comment: Try fast solver instead of exact

Comment: pls provide blend file if Allen's comment doesn't help